# What is the point of the skill tree "Totems" for Werewolves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I really don't get the point of the active skills for werewolves in Skyrim. Picking the perk, which should let me to summon 2 werewolves did nothing, as i'm unable to open anything but the werewolf skill tree. At first i thought this was a bug, but then i read about the "totems of hircine" quest, which actually lets me change the howls.

What is the logic in having those skills in the tree if you can only use those skills with quest obtained totems ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a perfect world, Bethesda would only release perfect software, and the Totem perk branch (not "skill tree") would be locked until you did the Totems of Hircine quests. Sadly the world is not perfect, and neither is Bethesda.

So, in this imperfect world, you just have to not pick perks that enhance abilities you don't have.

The perk you're talking about, *Totem of the Moon*, doesn't grant you the ability to summon werewolves, it only upgrades the summons you would already get from the Totem of Brotherhood, from normal wolves to werewolves. Once you complete the quest you can choose the Totem and your perk will apply.

To start the Totem quests, ask Aela the Huntress if there's any work to be done.

Comment: and if you've already done the totem quests, how do i get the abilities?

Answer (score 1):

The perks power up your totem powers. If you like these powers, you will like them more after you've invested in relevant perks.